# How to retrieve saml2 (SSO) Azure AD with AuthnRequest request in a backend application?

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have a web application that can already retrieve the saml2 via a business application (SSO) in Azure AD with AuthnRequest, from what I understand, when I make the request to retrieve the saml2 it scans the browser's cookies to get the login data, if it is not there logged in, I am redirected to the login screen.

Is it possible to retrieve saml2 from a backend application?

Is there any parameter in AuthnRequest that I pass (username and password, clientId) that Azure reads this parameter and returns saml2 to me?

I can already login to an application in azure ad but I don't know how to retrieve saml2 (SSO) in an enterprise application

I can already login to an application in azure ad but I don't know how to retrieve saml2 (SSO) in an enterprise application

Answer (score 0):

No, SAML does not work that way (regarding the user and password).  The authentication is initiated via the user's browser (either via a user request to the IdP with an IdP initiated workflow or a user request to the application).

It is possible for back end (SOAP based) messaging to retrieve the assertion but it is generally initiated via a user request to the application.

Could you initiate a SAML process from the server without a user, using a user and password - yes but you would need to have a script act as the user interacting with the SP (Service Provider aka application) and the IdP (Identity provider)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And through the OIDC is it possible? I'm looking at the Azure documentation and I always find a web application

Comment: I am not sure about OIDC

Comment: For OIDC, it's possible to use password grant-type or client credential grant-type for server to server authentication. If that security level suits you.